# compiling a c++ code using php

Tags: php, compilation

I was developing a online judge (*like topcoder/codeforces.com*) for our school .
But i dont know how to get a start-how can i evalute someones c++ code using php.
Also note , the code will use c++ & i need to provide some input stored in a file.
I have no problem in designing site (in php) and testing output produced.
It would be favourable , if i could use some external site (i dont own a server,funds less so free server!).

Thankyou in advanced.
-Adam

Comment: @John : I have no idea how to get started , i have never coped with such project ?

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious way to do this would be to call the compiler via system/exec on uploaded source. Probably this is the only way. I doubt there are C++ parsers/interpreters for PHP (it is theoretically possible however very complex and pointless).

This will be hard to do if you don't have a dedicated hosting as most probably every hosting provider is blocking calls to system/exec and even if they don't you wont have an access to a compiler.

If you don't fully trust your users (your schoolmates can hack) You will also have to "sandbox" application you build from code. You need to make sure no one will be able to read your filesystem / delete files / connect to database etc. You can do this via one or more from the following:

- give access only to closed list of headers/libs you trust (math etc)
- run application as a user that is created for this purpose only (simplest solution)
- use virtual machine
- etc.

You can check:

[Creating an online judge from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019731/creating-an-online-judge-from-scratch)

And maybe this will be useful:

https://github.com/anomit/loki

Comment: Thanks a lot @fsw , i am checking links for now & will let you know if i have further any problem ^_^
And i cant vote up now , it requires 15 reputation it says :|

Comment: does it works ? I am not able to install it . I am newbie and i couldnt understand how to install maybe?

Comment: Install instructions are in README file. Code seems very simple so you should start by reading it and checking how things work. as i see it is using a backend compiled app to build and run snippets instead of php exec but concept is the same.